# How to parse html content to text file with formatting?

Tags: javascript, html, export

I have an application in which user can do some actions with ajax calls. When ajax call is done then the results of the action is append into my div with `id = "log"`. I want to make a user option (button - Export) when he is done with his work that he can export his "activity log" into .txt file. So far i have succeed doing that but html converts into txt file with tags etc. I would like to remove tags and format a bit that .txt file but don't know how.

My HTML code is

```
<input type="button" value="Export" onclick="exportLog();">
<div id="log">
    <p>Action 1 successful</p>
    <p>Action 2 unsuccessful </p>
    <p>Action 4 - contact admin</p>
    <p>...etc</p>
</div>
```

Javascript code is

```
function exportLog(){
    var elHtml = document.getElementById('log').innerHTML;
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var mimeType = 'text/plain';

    link.setAttribute('download', 'logFile');
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType  +  ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
    link.click();
}
```

I did this with a help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084698/how-to-export-source-content-within-div-to-text-html-file). It works but my .txt file is like

```
<p>Action 1 successful</p><p>Action 2 unsuccessful </p><p>Action 4 - contact admin</p><p>...etc</p>
```

and i would like to look like

```
Action 1 successful
Action 2 unsuccessful 
Action 4 - contact admin
...etc
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Can user use another html tags? or only <p> will be?

Comment: Why is tag important? Is there anything special about this tag or i am missing something?

Comment: Because, I can propose to use regexp for this task. And this regexp must know what tags will be used.

Comment: Then only <p> tags allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Method:**
change `innerHTML` to `innerText`

Your working [code](https://jsfiddle.net/wmr1c0bx/)

I changed only this line

```
var elHtml = document.getElementById('log').innerText;
```

**Second method:**

you can use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) API

JsFiddler [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wmr1c0bx/1/)

PS : I am able to get the text with newline characters with both the methods

Please refer the screenshot of my text editor for your reference.

[image]

Comment: It removes the tags but still all values goes in 1 line, but as you can see on my question that i would like new line to each <p> tag.

Comment: Yes you are right, but why my notepad (windows 10) doesn't show me each line in own row and other programs do show it? Now I am confused a lot.

Comment: @KuKeC i have updated the answer with possible options. I can see the newline being applied in the formatting of the text and text editors recognise it correctly.

Comment: Thanks on fast and simple solution. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if to use only p tag, then this should work

```
var stringWithNewLines = logContent.replace(/<p>(.+?)<\/p>/g, function(str, p1, offset, s) {
      return p1 + "\n"; 
});
```