# How to write the saveTable function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function createTable(){
    var _table = document.getElementById("test");
    var newRow = _table.insertRow(1);
    var cell0 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(1);
    cell0.innerHTML = "x";
    cell1.innerHTML = 60;
    }

function saveTable(){
   document.execCommand("saveas",,"/tmp/test.html");
    }
```

```html
<p>to create my table</p>
<input type="button" value="to create new table" onclick="createTable()" />
<input type="button" value="to save table as /tmp/test.html" oncilck="saveTable()" />
<table id="test" bodrder=1px>
<tr>
    <td>f1</td>
    <td>f2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

when the table was created by function createTable,i want to get a file /tmp/test.html whose content is as following

```html
<table id="test">
<tr>
<td>f1</td>
<td>f2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>x</td>
<td>60</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How to fulfil my saveTable function to do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a blob for this as explained here:

https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/

and here:

[How to export source content within div to text/html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084698/how-to-export-source-content-within-div-to-text-html-file)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

 
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>to create my table</p>

  <form>
    <input type="button" value="to create new table" onclick="createTable()"> <input type="button" value=
    "to save table as /tmp/test.html" onclick="saveTable()">
  </form>

  <table id="test" bodrder="1px">
    <tr>
      <td>f1</td>

      <td>f2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  
   <script>
function createTable() {
 var _table = document.getElementById("test");
 var newRow = _table.insertRow(1);
 var cell0 = newRow.insertCell(0);
 var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(1);
 cell0.innerHTML = "x";
 cell1.innerHTML = 60;
}

function saveTable() {
 var textToSave = document.getElementById("test").outerHTML;
 var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {
   type : "text/html"
  });
 var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
 var fileNameToSaveAs = "/tmp/test.html";

 var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
 downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
 downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
 downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
 downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
 downloadLink.style.display = "none";
 document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

 downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event) {
 document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}

  </script>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Two problems remains.

Comment: 1. location to save file

Comment: what i want is `/tmp/test.html` ,What i get with the code is  `/Downloads/_tmp_test.html`

Comment: 2.content in  /Downloads/_tmp_test.html

Comment: Only one word in /Downloads/_tmp_test.html,`undefined`,not some lines of html.

Comment: You had a typo  also.. it said   `oncilck='saveTable()'`  instead of `onclick`

Updated answer to reflect changes