# HTML wrap approach

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building an app that allows the user to create an HTML page. When the user downloads their page I take all the HTML within the canvas div and save it as an HTML file, containing their page elements.

Now the problem is that I need to find a way to wrap the page with like this before they download.

Before Download

```
<div id="page-area">
   // PAGE ELEMENTS
</div>
```

Result After Download

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>page</title>

  <head>

    <body>
      // PAGE ELEMENTS
    </body>

</html>
```

What's the best way to wrap multiple elements with HTML, head, body, and other basic HTML structure tags? Looking for a jQuery solution or raw JavaScript.

So for example if I could take all of these elements

```html
<ul>
  <li>List</li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs">
  <span>test</span>
  </tabs>
```

And wrap then with the basic HTML structure like this

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>List</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs">
    <span>test</span>
    </tabs>
</body>

</html>
```

How would I do that with jQuery?

Comment: Why don't you go check this out. appendTo http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Comment: Possible you are looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033011/downloading-the-content-of-a-div-as-a-separate-html-file). Append your data as said by above user that download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHeMz/218/) for code reference.

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    ...
</div>
```

JS:

```
var a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));    
a.download = "export.html";
html = "<html><head></head><body>" 
html += document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
html += "</body></html>" 
a.href = "data:text/html," + html;
a.innerHTML = "[Download HTML]";
```

Comment: Works great. Now if only theres some sort of plugin that can properly indent and organize the code because currently it looks like this. <html><head><title></title></head>